# Displaying Custom DataGridViewColumn in the DataGridView column type picker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I created a custom DataGridView Column by extending the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and DataGridViewTextBoxCell classes.  Both classes are public, however, my custom column does not appear in the ColumnType dropdown menu in the Add/Edit Column menu option for the DataGridView control as seen in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjxam.jpg

I've researched about Custom DataGridView columns and cannot find anything that I'm missing.

I also created the following simple test custom DGV column class:

```
public class TestColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public TestColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new TestCell();
    }
}

public class TestCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override object Clone()
    {
        TestCell cell = base.Clone() as TestCell;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win Forms DatagridView. How to add custom column from designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427196/win-forms-datagridview-how-to-add-custom-column-from-designer)

Comment: I've already followed everything in that forum post but still having the issue.

Comment: Clicking `Rebuild Solution` or `Clean Solution` + `Build Solution` didn't work? If not, have you tried making another test-column, then rebuilding to see if it also fails (to test if somehow the first custom column was corrupted)?

Comment: I've tried creating another more simple custom DGV column and recompiled...same issue.  Cannot get the custom column to appear in the Designer Add/Edit Column option.  It's been driving me nuts for the past 4 hours.  I've searched all the articles and forum posts on the first 2 pages of Google results and still no luck.  I've even restarted VS just in case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this behavior. Using your `TestColumn` worked just fine for me, even when it was in a different `namespace`. The last thing I can think is to test if it's just this project - if adding a test column to a test project and form will work.

Comment: I created a new Winforms project and used the 2 DGV column classes I created and now it shows up in the column type picker dropdown.  So seems to be something with the project.  Thanks for you help!  Appreciate it.

Comment: After much testing and experimenting with different options, I found out that the reason why my custom DGV column was not showing in the designer column type dropdown was because my project was set to build in 64-bit rather any Any CPU.